# I can vote more than 40 times?

Tags: support, voting

Today I have earned the Vox Populi badge. But when I have logged in 2 hours after this I could vote! Why? I don't know. I added a screenshot.

> [image]

Comment: Probably some posts you have voted on have been deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when a post that you voted is deleted. The count of your votes doesn't change, but you can vote one post more (because the count on which the limit is based is decreased).